# Sevice Cloud Console tab change to trigger custom javascript

Tags: service-cloud-console

We are trying to integrate an external application to the Service Cloud and we would need Service Cloud Console to fire out an AJAX request [with the id of the case/contact viewed] every time there is a tab change in the Service Cloud Consoled.
This is so that other application could bring up information related to the tab visible in the Service Cloud window.

Is there a way to trigger a javascript function when the user switches tabs in the Service Cloud Console?